# Detect when the transition of a new pushed view ends

Tags: iphone, objective-c, three20

In an application built on top of **Three20**, how can I detect, after a new view is pushed, when the transition ends?

If I use **viewDidLoad**, it's call when the view is loaded into memory, but the transition may has not started yet.

Comment: How are you animating the view transition?

Comment: I'm using TTNavigator for the navigation: e.g  [[TTNavigator navigator] openURLAction:action];

Comment: (void)viewDidLoad:(BOOL)animated is never called. I just tested it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you've used UIView animation methods (pre-iOS4), you can use `+setAnimationDidStopSelector:` or if you've used the new block-based animation methods, you can use any of the methods that allow you to set a completion handler like [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIView/transitionWithView%3aduration%3aoptions%3aanimations%3acompletion%3a).

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using `viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {`?

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated;
```